# Want to create a TCP server

Tags: bash, sockets, tcp

Hey I am trying to create a TCP server which communicate with a client(eg nc).
The functionality I've been trying to achieve is very simple:

1. echo:
   command: "ECHO "
   response: ""
2. data storing:
   command: "SET  "
   response: "!200"
   if no more values can  be inputted give out response "!err"

3.data retrieval:
command: "GET "
output: ""
if not found give out response "!error"

After using `nc -l localhost 3000` i am not able to use any other command

EDIT: After seeing some downvotes i figured i was not clear with my problem,which is i am running this code

```
nc -l localhost 3000

while read -r cmd; do
  case $cmd in
    d) date ;;
    q) break ;;
    *) echo 'What?'
  esac
done
```

in the cmdline i am not able to write any thing.
so i am not able to confirm if the d,q,* are working or not

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site, so what is your actual question? And this is not a code writing service, so what code have you attempted so far to try to implement this server you want?

Comment: Hey its my fault that I was not clear with my question ill edit it but i think i wrote my problem in the last line. that i was not able to use any other command after the initial line. and also i know this is not a code writing service i was only here to solve my doubt as i am very new to socket programming .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `nc` supports it, you can use the '-e' option: put your loop in a new file `handle_client.sh`, then start the server with

```
nc -l localhost 3000 -e ./handle_client.sh
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this , I searched online and found this ``` coproc nc -l localhost 3000

while read -r cmd; do
  case $cmd in
    d) date ;;
    q) break ;;
    *) echo 'What?'
  esac
done <&"${COPROC[0]}" >&"${COPROC[1]}"

kill "$COPROC_PID" ``` this worked for me i vaguely understood what the code is doing but still not understood what the actual problem was

Comment: @IshmeetSingh The problem was that while `nc` is running, the script execution is blocked until the client disconnects. Then the `read` doesn't work, because there is no opened socket anymore!

Comment: With your solution, you spawn a new process while `nc` is still running, so it can access the still-alive socket via `COPROC[0]`